# Set of m-vectors

Tags: matrices

In my book (matrix computations by Gill) there's a term used quite a lot which I don't understand/find what is its meaning.

> The set of all **$m$-vectors** that are linear combinations s of the columns of the $m \times n$  matrix $A$ is called range space, column space or simply the range of $A$.

Does "m-vectors" refer to vectors of dimension $m$?

Comment: Yes, I think it refers to a vector with $m$ coordinates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be elements of $\mathbb{R}^m$, i.e. vectors of dimension $m$.

See for example the definition on page 41 of [Elementary Linear Algebra By Stewart Venit, Wayne Bishop, Jason Brown](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hzn8QdXM7ZcC&pg=PA204&lpg=PA204&dq=%22The%20set%20of%20all%20m-vectors%22&source=bl&ots=L8p7JuEPjX&sig=pGf8BhjSbWKkwIcMUothxj9IPB8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8CWGUuLNOeHH7Aapj4CwBw&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=m-vector&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix, say $A = (v_1, v_2, . . . , v_n ) $ where $i$ th column of $A$ is $v_i$ and each $v_i$ is a vector in $\mathbb{F}^m$ . With this set up, by set of all $m-$vectors that are linear combinations of columns of $A$ they means :

set of all $ \alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2 +...+ \alpha_k v_k$  such that $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F} $ and $1 \le k \le m$.